# PHP - failed to output no data where no data in table

Tags: php, pdo

I've tried to find any reference to display data where no data in table for an hours, but I'm not yet found a code to fix the issue

I've this code:

```
//function

function readAll(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name." ORDER BY id_nilai ASC";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}

//execute
$pro3 = new Nilai($db);
$stmt3 = $pro3->readAll();
while ($row3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            // not yet fix how to display no data
            //if($row3==false){  tried to change $row3==0 still won't work
                //echo "No Data";
            //}
              //die(var_dump($row3)); showing `bool(false)`
            echo $row3['ket_nilai'] (echo $row3['jum_nilai'])
        }
```

any idea how to do?

Comment: you want to display some text when no data found?

Comment: your question is unclear for me

Comment: @AgamBanga yes, i want to display some text when no data found in database table

Comment: like `if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { /* do stuff */ } else { echo "no data"; }` ?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile sorry if my question to ambigous, im not good to ask formal question, the point is i want to `echo "no data"` when `select` query doesn't show any value

Comment: only *one* can be the FGITW ^^

Comment: @dreq I get you now, see the answers below and try them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to display some text when no data found in database table

You need to fetch the results before entering the loop, check if you do get the results then if you do enter the loop else display the message

see bellow code :

```
<?php

//function

function readAll(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name." ORDER BY id_nilai ASC";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}

//execute
$pro3 = new Nilai($db);
$stmt3 = $pro3->readAll();
$results = $stmt3->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($results) > 0){

    foreach($results as $row3){

        //display them
     echo $row3['ket_nilai'] ;
     echo $row3['jum_nilai'];
    }
}else{

    echo "No data available";
}
?>
```

Comment: that's work for me sir, thanks!, but i want to know why `$stmt3->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` must declare on top of php? it's mean i can't use if on my comment code?

Comment: you are fetching the data before entering the loop in that way its easy to see if you are getting any data, as you will count the data next

Comment: ohh i see, so i should fetching the data before entering the loop..
thanks sir for the information, now i know a bit about fetching, :)